# Difference between random draws from scipy.stats....rvs and numpy.random

Tags: python, numpy, random, scipy

It seems if it is the same distribution, drawing random samples from `numpy.random` is faster than doing so from `scipy.stats.-.rvs`. I was wondering what causes the speed difference between the two?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

scipy.stats.uniform actually uses numpy, here is the corresponding function in stats (mtrand is an alias for numpy.random)

```
class uniform_gen(rv_continuous):
    def _rvs(self):
        return mtrand.uniform(0.0,1.0,self._size)
```

scipy.stats has a bit of overhead for error checking and making the interface more flexible. The speed difference should be minimal as long as you don't call uniform.rvs in a loop for each draw. You can get instead all random draws at once, for example (10 million)

```
>>> rvs = stats.uniform.rvs(size=(10000, 1000))
>>> rvs.shape
(10000, 1000)
```

Here is the long answer, that I wrote a while ago:

The basic random numbers in scipy/numpy are created by
Mersenne-Twister PRNG in numpy.random. The random numbers for
distributions in numpy.random are in cython/pyrex and are pretty fast.

scipy.stats doesn't have a random number generator, random numbers are
obtained in one of three ways:

- directly from numpy.random, e.g. normal, t, ...  pretty fast
- random numbers by transformation of other random numbers that are
  available in numpy.random, also pretty fast because this operates on
  entire arrays of numbers
- generic: the only generic generation random number generation is by
  using the ppf (inverse cdf) to transform uniform random numbers.
  This is relatively fast if there is an explicit expression for the
  ppf, but can be *very* slow if the ppf has to be calculated
  indirectly. For example if only the pdf is defined, then the cdf is
  obtained through numerical integration and the ppf is obtained through
  an equation solver. So a few distributions are very slow.

Comment: Thank you. I'm running MCMC routines so I have to draw a lot iteratively, so I will use numpy.random.

Answer (score 6):

I ran into this today and just wanted to add some timing details to this question. I saw what joon mentioned where, in particular, random numbers from the normal distribution were much more quickly generated with `numpy` than from `rvs` in `scipy.stats`. As user333700 mentioned there is some overhead with `rvs` but if you are generating an array of random values then that gap closes compared to `numpy`.  Here is a jupyter timing example:

```
from scipy.stats import norm
import numpy as np

n = norm(0, 1)
%timeit -n 1000 n.rvs(1)[0]
%timeit -n 1000 np.random.normal(0,1)

%timeit -n 1000 a = n.rvs(1000)
%timeit -n 1000 a = [np.random.normal(0,1) for i in range(0, 1000)]
%timeit -n 1000 a = np.random.randn(1000)
```

This, on my run with `numpy` version 1.11.1 and `scipy` 0.17.0, outputs:

```
1000 loops, best of 3: 46.8 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 492 ns per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 115 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 343 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 61.9 µs per loop
```

So just generating one random sample from `rvs` was almost 100x slower than using `numpy` directly. However, if you are generating an array of values than the gap closes (115 to 61.9 microseconds).

If you can avoid it, probably don't call `rvs` to get one random value a ton of times in a loop.